# SecurityContextHolder.getContext (). GetAuthentication (). GetPrincipal () can only get the username

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

SecurityContextHolder.getContext (). GetAuthentication (). GetPrincipal () can only get the username,
I actually want to get a user object.

Comment: @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                .exceptionTranslator(new GzsWebResponseExceptionTranslator());
    }

Comment: If you get username then you can retrive user object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct. You have to make the username field unique. Then you will be able in the repository to create a method which will allow you to recover a user by his username. And there you can get the field you need.